# Need Java array help using scanner class to output an average and sort method

Tags: java, arrays

After several hours, I haven't made progress on making a method to output the average. I also need to make a sort class. Overall, the assignment needs.

Develop methods to:

- ‘main’ method   Print the array
- Sort the array
- Determine the highest value
- Determine the lowest value
- Calculate the average value (double)

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Arrayassignment {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner sin=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter an intiger for array size.");

int number= sin.nextInt();

int array[]=new int[number];

System.out.println("Array size " + number + " initiated.\n");


System.out.println("Now enter the array intigers");
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
{  
    array[i]=sin.nextInt();

 }

System.out.println ("The highest number in the array is " + max (array) );
System.out.println ("The smallest number in the array is " + min (array) );
//System.out.println ("The average of the numbers in the array is " ;
}
public static int max ( int ... arg )
{
 if ( arg.length == 0) 
 { 
   System.out.println(" empty arguement list ")  ;
   return 0;
 }
 int largest = arg [0];
 for (int i = 1; i < arg.length; i++ )
 {
   if (arg [i] > largest)
       largest = arg[i];
 }
 return largest;
 }

 public static int min ( int ... arg )
 {
 if ( arg.length == 0) 
 { 
   System.out.println(" empty arguement list ")  ;
   return 0;
 }
 int smallest = arg [0];
 for (int i = 1; i < arg.length; i++ )
 {
   if (arg [i] < smallest)
       smallest = arg[i];
 }
 return smallest;
```

Comment: Where you exactly stuck now ?

Comment: So what is your actual problem here?  All I can see is code that calculates `min` and `max` .... and NO ATTEMPT to address the remaining requirements.

Comment: I have tried making something for the average method but I just keep fooling myself. I have tried /* public static double avg ( double ... arg)
     {
       double sum = arg [0];
    for (int i = 0; i < arg.length; i++){
     
    // calculate average
    double mid = arg [i] / arg.length  ;
      
    return sum;
     }

Comment: OK ... so how would you calculate an average using a pencil and paper?  Compare that with what you have written.

Comment: I need to figure out how to get all of my numbers to output a total sum. hopefully, I can make the average work from there

Answer (score 1):

```
int sum = 0;
for (int d : arg ) sum += d;
double average = 1.0d * sum / arg .length;
```

this will help you to find average...

Comment: Hey guys - you are not helping him >>learn<< by doing his homework for him!

Comment: Then downvote will be on the question...why on the answer? And he also made some attempt to solve...

Comment: Since I am an online student and this is my first time reaching out for help, it shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: If some answer has worked for you, you should mark it as accepted. So that question status becomes answered.

Comment: @sjames14...You can mark this as accepted by clicking 'check' icon in the left of the answer post...

Comment: @sjames14 - I have no problem with you asking for help.  However, this is not helping you (much).  What these guys >>should<< be doing is giving you help that allows you to work out the answer for yourself.  You will learn much more by going through the process for your self.

Answer (score 1):

To sort find min and max you can use TreeSet collection class. If you are using primitive type or a wrapper class, in this case no need to add any comparison logic. otherwise you need to implement comparator or comparable methods. Here is a example of TreeSet for min and max data http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/a-simple-treeset-example/ . For calculating average i suggest you can use a local variable and for each time you add a number to TreeSet you can update the average. For eg when you add a new number p to current average value v, calculate latest average as v = (v*size + p)/++size;

Comment: I don't think I can do the TreeSet thing with the scanner input.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8+ you could use [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) and [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) like

```
int[] arr = { 3, 1, 2 };
IntSummaryStatistics stats = IntStream.of(arr).summaryStatistics();
System.out.printf("Min: %d, Max: %d, Average: %.2f%n", //
        stats.getMin(), stats.getMax(), stats.getAverage());
IntStream.of(arr).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the average like this:

```
int sum = 0;
double avg = 0;
for (int i=0;i<array.length; i++){
   sum+=array[i];
}
avg = sum/array.length;
```